# ng_patch and VLAN priority

Tags: freebsd, vlan

I have a VLAN interface in FreeBSD 9:

```
vlan34: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=103<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
        inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%vlan34 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb
        inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxnetmask 0xfffff800 broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        vlan: 34 parent interface: em0
```

What I need is to set all packets sent from this interface with VLAN priority set to 4.

Based on the manpage of FreeBSD ([vlan(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vlan)), there is no support other than VLAN tagging.

```
No 802.1Q features except VLAN tagging are implemented.
```

It seems the only workaround without patching base system is employ ng_patch. However, in manpage of [ng_patch(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ng_patch), the example is nothing to do with this goal and it's pretty hard to understand.

```
 /usr/sbin/ngctl -f- <<-SEQ
     mkpeer ipfw: patch 200 in
     name ipfw:200 ttl_add
     msg ttl_add: setconfig { count=1 csum_flags=1 ops=[     \
         { mode=2 value=3 length=1 offset=8 } ] }
 SEQ
 /sbin/ipfw add 150 netgraph 200 ip from any to simplex.remote.net
```

Is there any example on modifying VLAN priority with ng_patch? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do (ie, what exactly needs to be prioritized about the VLAN - traffic in and out of the machine, traffic across the network, etc)?

Comment: @MaQleod I updated the question :-)

Comment: I'm not sure that ng_patch is quite what you are looking for (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ng_patch&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE). Anytime you want to prioritize packets, you typically will use QoS. With VLANs, that means utilizing tagging. When I used to setup VoIP networks, we'd put the VoIP traffic on a vlan, tag it, and set QoS on the switch to prioritize packets tagged for that VLAN. Now if you want to do this leaving the BSD box instead of at the switch (though I'd recommend both), you'll need to setup QoS on the BSD box.

Comment: @MaQleod Actually I don't want to do anything on QoS. It's just a requirement of my ISP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [patch](http://www.watson.org/~robert/freebsd/20120118-ieee8021q.diff) by Robert Watson to enable this.

Comment: This patch does not fit neither HEAD nor 9-stable. :-(